# What is Pension Day and Family Payment Day in Australia?

Tags: australia, terminology

The title pretty much says it. My parents went to Australia and brought me back a calendar. I see those days every other week, throughout the year, but I can't find a good explanation on what they are. Probably because they're just apart of Australian society. So can I get a decent explanation of what those days mean?

Comment: Please note that very few Australian calendars have these days marked. Most just have the public holidays for each state/capital city. Some calendars have the phases of the moon or minority religions' holidays marked as well.

Comment: This one is weird, those two days are marked, term start dates are on there (whatever that means) Let's just go I have no clue what half of what is on there means. :)

Comment: Australian school years are divided into four "terms", the start dates refer to these: https://online.det.nsw.edu.au/calendar/?do=setViewPeriod&categoryid=21&viewType=yearView

Comment: The school terms vary by state. So your calendar probably only has the term dates for one state. It might have holidays for different states too. Labour day and the Queen's birthday are observed on different dates in some states. Some holidays are national like Australia Day. See http://www.australia.gov.au/topics/australian-facts-and-figures/public-holidays and http://www.australia.gov.au/topics/australian-facts-and-figures/school-term-dates. The most populous states are New South Wales (NSW) and Victoria (Vic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - they are the days when government support payments are made. They're in the calendar presumably for budgeting purposes.

**Pension Day**

The most common types of pension payments are age pensions -

> The Age Pension is designed to provide income support to older Australians who need it, while encouraging pensioners to maximise their overall incomes. The Age Pension is paid to people who meet age and residency requirements, subject to a means test. Pension rates are indexed to ensure they keep pace with Australian price and wage increases.

https://www.dss.gov.au/our-responsibilities/seniors/benefits-payments/age-pension

... and disability support pensions -

> Financial support for people who have a physical, intellectual, or psychiatric condition that stops them from working or who are permanently blind.

http://www.humanservices.gov.au/customer/services/centrelink/disability-support-pension

**Family Payment Day**

> We provide a range of payments and services that help you look after your children’s education and health care, and any family issues that may come up along the way.

http://www.humanservices.gov.au/customer/subjects/payments-for-families

Answer (score 3):

Those are the days that the government deposits into your account either your [retirement pension](https://www.css.gov.au/your-future/css-pensioner/paydays/) money or money due you to help support your [children](http://www.humanservices.gov.au/customer/services/centrelink/family-tax-benefit-part-a-part-b). The latter has income, residency, and other requirements.